# Accessing text file executing JAR from command line

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, jar, inputstream

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LIvk.png)

With my file structure above, how do I go about accessing the text files located in Resource folder? In the code below fileName = synonyms.txt (for example).

```
InputStream in = FileOperator.class.getResourceAsStream("/Resources/" + fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Getting the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at PlagarismDetector.FileOperator.getSynMap(FileOperator.java:25)
    at PlagarismDetector.PlagarismDetector.getPercentage(PlagarismDetector.java:35)
```

Maybe there is something wrong with how I am executing the jar? In the terminal I am doing:

java -jar .../tripAdvisorPlagarism.jar synonyms.txt input1.txt input2.txt

Comment: it would appear that your `InputStream in` is null. As a matter of best practice, you should check this condition beforehand (throw an exception with a better error message). Next guess, your path is probably wrong.